# Query to limit number of requests per day

Tags: mysql

I am trying to limit the user to perform only 5 requests per day. To do that, I am counting the number of request already performed during the same day using the query below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE date_field >= CURDATE()
```

This gives me requests already performed days before. All I need is only the number of request performed in the course today. Any idea please?

Comment: what data type is the date_field?

Comment: timestamp with default current_timestamp thanks

Comment: What does the data in `date_field` look like?  If it is valid MySQL data field, then your query should work.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBrant you are right, my query is wrong as I needed to add whose number of requests I am looking for by specifying the user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE date_field >= CURDATE()
```

... will return the number of rows where date_field is greater than or equal to today if date_field is a date datatype. That is, ensure time is not a component but it certainly cannot return "requests already performed days before" unless there is a bug in the value stored in date_field column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE date(date_field) = CURDATE()
```

Assuming `date_field` is a timestamp/datetime field, `date()` will extract just the date part and evaluate it against the current date. You can read more about it on **[MySQL's Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)**